# support of $tan^{-1}(X/Y)$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

If $ -\infty < X, Y < \infty$, what is the support of

\begin{equation}
\textrm{tan}^{-1}\frac{X}{Y}.
\end{equation}

I thought it is $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, but I saw in a book that it is $(-\pi, \pi)$.

Any reason for this difference?

Comment: try reading about [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) and how this depends on the sign of $X$ and the sign of $Y$ rather than just the sign of the quotient

Answer (score 2):

The range of

$$\tan^{-1}(z)$$

only covers $\pi$ radians, usually taken to be $[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$.

Unless the expression

$$\tan^{-1}\frac XY$$ denotes something different from

$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac XY\right),$$ the book is wrong.

Comment: It is defined as $tan^{-1}(X/Y)$. It is actually a question relating to transformation of random variables. X and Y are independent and has standard normal distribution. $A^2 = X^2 + Y^2$ and $\phi = tan^{-1}(X/Y)$. To apply transformation of random variables, I want to see whether $\phi = tan^{-1}(X/Y)$ is one-to-one. It is one-to-one when $-\pi/2 < \phi < \pi/2$. The question wants to show that $\phi$ is a uniformly distributed random variable on $(-\pi, \pi)$. If $\phi$ takes this support it is not a one-to-one function.

Comment: @shani: one-to-one ? Absolutely not. All $\lambda X/\lambda Y$ map to the same $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks for point that out. I was thinking about graph of a $tan(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have a planar region here since the function has two arguments.  The natural domain of this function is the plane less the $x$--axis.

Comment: You mean the $x$-axis, do you? Why should $\tan^{-1}(0/1)$ be 'unnatural'?

Comment: You have $x/y$; division by zero rules out all points where $y = 0$.

Comment: Yes,  but the  $y$-axis consists the points $(x=0,y)$ whereas the $x$-axis is the set of  points $(x,y=0)$. So if you do not want to have $y=0$ you have to exclude the $x$-axis and **not** the  $y$-axis, as you did in your answer

Comment: coffee hadn't taken effect.